# How to query the latest submission by time in praw?

Tags: python, praw

I am using `python praw` to query data from `reddit`. And I can use below code to query the latest 10 posts for the topic `movies`.

```
for submission in reddit.subreddit('movies').new(limit=10):
    print(submission)
```

I wonder how I can query the posts posted within the last 5 minutes.

Comment: You could try getting x posts and comparing the `created` time for each of them with the current time - 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this simply, but something like this should work. It will find the age of each post in minutes and check if it is less than 5. Then process the post only if it is.

```
import time

SUBMISSION_LIMIT = 10 # some number more than the number of posts every 5 minutes
for submission in reddit.subreddit('movies').new(limit=SUBMISSION_LIMIT):
    minutes_since_post = (time.time() - submission.created_utc) / 60
    if minutes_since_post < 5:
        print(submission)
```